# Angular $promise and global objects

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading a lot about promises in Angular and how to use them, how to defer, how to reject/resolve them, how to use .then, .finally, etc.

Now, I am trying to do something that may not have any sense at all, or maybe it does, I just need to check if it does and how to do it before I become more mad than I think I am:

I have an app, I want that app to have a global object that can be accessed by different controllers, actually even the templates have access to it, and I want everyone to wait until the object is filled with data before accessing it.

I've called that object "myProfile", which is my user, and of course I want many controllers/templates to access my username and profile details without needing to make calls to anywhere all the time, just typing something like "$rootscope.myProfile".

That seems to work, templates wait for it to be filled, controllers get access to it... and I only need to make an initial call on loading the app to ProfileService.getMyUser, actually I created this factory which creates the global object:

```
function myUserProfile(ProfileService, $rootScope, $analytics) {
    return ProfileService.getWhoAmI()
        .then(function(user) {
            $rootScope.myProfile = user;
            $analytics.setUserProperties({
                // blah
            });
        });
}

myApp.factory('myUserProfile', myUserProfile);
myApp.run(function (myUserProfile) {
   // The factory will be instantiated here as has been injected
});
```

Yes, it also helps on setting analytics stuff.

My problem is, if I try to access the object before it's filled, I get an undefined error:

```
console.log($rootScope.myProfile);
$rootScope.myProfile.testProp = 300;
console.log($rootScope.myProfile);
```

Log:

```
Cannot set property 'testProp' of undefined
```

To be able to wait until it's filled in a more manual way, I can set another $rootscope variable to the promise, like:

```
    $rootScope.myProfileRetrieved = ProfileService.getWhoAmI()
        .then(function(user) {
            $rootScope.myProfile = user;
        });
```

Then I could do this:

```
$rootScope.myProfileRetrieved.then(function () {
    console.log($rootScope.myProfile);
    $rootScope.myProfile.testProp = 300;
    console.log($rootScope.myProfile);
});
```

And that works. But I'm not very convinced that this is a good practice, it even sounds wrong somehow.

So my question is, do I have to access it using a .then() all the time so I make sure the object is there before accessing it if I want to write on it? Is there a way of doing what I want which is: "wait until object arrives, then write" without adding a .then() all the time?

Am I getting it all wrong and promises are not expected to be used this way?

Thanks so much, reading too many technical stuff can make your brain collapse with too much data.

**Update**
Ok, thinking about it, I think my original idea isn't that far from what it should be, just using the factory instead than the $rootscope, so on the controller I can inject the factory and then:

```
function myController($scope, ... , myUserProfile, someOtherService) {
        someOtherService.get().then(function (data) {
            myUserProfile.then(function () {
                 $rootscope.myProfile.newProperty = data.Whatever;
            });
        });
}
```

Probably that has more sense?

Comment: I think the best thing is to make sure you initialise enough of the object early so that you can safely access the parts you need. For example `$rootScope.myProfile = {}` and then `$rootScope.myProfile.testProp` will be `undefined` but won't throw an error. Then when you have the user object you can either overwrite or update the empty object.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea, thanks. Though it still has some flags as I may need to read some data before doing something else, but would solve the undefined issue.

Comment: This recipe works fine for services that return an empty object, but isn't too useful for scope properties. They will return undefined when they shouldn't, and nested objects will still throw errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myUserProfile(ProfileService, $rootScope, $analytics) {
    return ProfileService.getWhoAmI()
        .then(function(user) {
            $rootScope.$emit('myProfile');
            $rootScope.myProfile = user;
            $analytics.setUserProperties({
                // blah
            });
        });
}
```

Then

```
$rootScope.$on('myProfile', function () { ... })
```

or

```
$rootScope.$watch('myProfile', function (newVal) {
    if (!newVal) return;
    ...
})
```

goes in all dependent places. Not too elegant but that's the price of async app-wide dependency.

> Probably that has more sense?

Not really, no, updating $rootScope from the controller doesn't look too good. $rootScope is prone to be misused, but in the first case it is justified just because it got events and $watch there.

For more complex app prerequisites I find the following recipe useful (if the application is based on route controllers, route `resolve` can be used instead of `app.run` and init event)

```
app.controller('AppController', function($scope, service1) {
    var initWatcher = $scope.$root.$watch('init', function (init) {
        if (!init) return;
        initWatcher();

        console.log(service1.data);
    });
});

app.factory('service1', function ($timeout) {
    var service1 = {};

    Object.defineProperty(service1, 'init', { enumerable: false, value: function () {
        return somePromise.then(function () {
                angular.extend(service1, {
                    data: 'data'
                });
                return service1;
            });
    }});

    return service1;

});

app.run(function ($rootScope, $q, service1, service2, service3) {
        service1.init().then(function (resolvedService1) {
            return $q.all({
                    service2: service2.init(),
                    service3: service3.init()
                });
        })
        .then(function (resolved) {
            $rootScope.init = true;
        });
});
```

Comment: Î'm not totally convinced of this approach. In my last example I have 2 requests, I need the two of them to succceed before I make the changes. So if myProfile request hasn't finished when the otherService has, it waits for it. Your approach may have a problem in case userProfile finishes before otherService does, as the emit will happen too soon. If I add it to the scope, how do I know that otherService did it's part? This is, I have 2 requests, even if both of them emit, do I need to set flags on the controller to know both succeeded? -> continues

Comment: If by when otherService succeeds myProfile hasn't, how do I wait for it? I think the idea of the promises is precisely that you can add "then"s to a cue so that you can wait until all promises have succeeded and then do something. If by when otherService finishes myProfile hasnt, it will wait, if myProfile already did, I won't miss the emit as the promise will be resolved ans just proceed.

Comment: Check the updated answer, this recipe helps me to eliminate some promise mess for more sophisticated scenarios.